# How can I delay the output of a button in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button

I am working on a button where you click it and a random number 1-50 appears. But once I got into it, I realized it was kind of boring so I am going to add a noise that plays for around 10 seconds and then the number appears. But the problem is that now that I tried to add the delay to the button it does not put the output number.

Here is my code (Dont mind the part about where the button is disabled because that is just to stop the cheating. There are other parts to this. This is just the code for this part I need help with):

```
<button id="rnum" 
        onclick="numFunction();setTimeout(delayFunction, 10500);" 
        disabled>
    Random Number
</button>

<p id="randnum"></p>

<script>
    function delayFunction()
    function numFunction() {
        var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 50) + 1);
        document.getElementById("randnum").innerHTML = x;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Where are the curly-brackets? `function delayFunction()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function delayFunction(callback){
  setTimeout(callback, 2000)
}

function numFunction() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 50) + 1);
    document.getElementById("randnum").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<button id="rnum" 
        onclick="delayFunction(numFunction)">
Random Number
</button>

<p id="randnum"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Random Number

```
          <p id="randnum"></p>

          <script>
          function numFunction() {
             setTimeout(function(){
              var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 50) + 1);
              document.getElementById("randnum").innerHTML = x;
             }, 10500);
          }
          </script>
```

Comment: cant format correctly on phone, but this is how you use the settimeout function ^